# Codename One for windows phone 8

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, windows-phone-8.1, codenameone, live-tile

Can I make an application using Codename One for Android, iOS ,and Windows Phone 8 from a single code base, but yet provide support for windows phone 8 feature like live tiles ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049363/somebody-know-how-to-use-live-tiles-with-phonegap-and-windows-phone-7

Comment: I want to make an app for IOS, Android and windows phone using codename one but I want to add live tiles to my app in the windows phone app so is that applicable using Codename One ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use native features using the [NativeInterfaces](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) concept however, I have no idea if live tiles would specifically be supported.